# What tax filings are required for real estate transactions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, irs

I intend to purchase real estate with cash from a family member via quitclaim.

What tax forms are we required to file reporting the sale?

Comment: Don't forget to file all the non-IRS forms: the local government wants to know who owns the property. Of course if the "owner" isn't really the owner the quitclaim deed is worthless.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Right. In this case the title issue is pretty well established due to court action.

Answer (score 1):

For the buyer - none (except for, potentially, 1099-S - see below). For the seller, it goes on [form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8949,-Sales-and-Other-Dispositions-of-Capital-Assets), and from it to [Schedule D](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Schedule-D-%28Form-1040%29,-Capital-Gains-and-Losses). Depending on the seller's situation, additional filings and forms may be required (depreciation recapture, passive losses recovery, primary residence exclusion, gift tax, etc etc).

If you're not going through a regular transaction via a title/escrow company or a broker, then [you do need to provide 1099-S](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099s/ar02.html#d0e221) to the seller.

Comment: Are you certain I don't need to provide a 1099-S?

Comment: You're right, you do.